# position child elements in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Good day. I'm having trouble figuring out how to position child elements of a `flexbox` when `flex-direction:column` is used.

How to position `sign up` next to `sign in`
[image]

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css"/>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="login-container">
        <h2 class="active">sign in</h2>
        <h2 class="inactive">sign up</h2>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Enter first name">
            <span>first name</span>
            <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Enter last name">
            <span>last name</span>
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
            <span>email</span>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-btn">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
body, .submit-btn {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.login-container {
    /*position:relative;*/
    /*align-items: center;*/
    flex-direction: column;
    display:flex;
    height:560px;
    width:405px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:60px 60px;
    box-shadow: 0 30px 60px -5px;
}

h2 {
    padding-left: 12px;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    position: relative;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

Comment: Dont use a column would be the obvious method. Then just make the form 100% wide and allow wrapping

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments. Removing `flex-direction`, making `form width:100%` and making `flex-wrap: wrap` solves the problem.
`